$\inf_{n\in \mathbb{N}^*} \left\{\frac{3^n}{2^n} \right\} > 0$?
The fractional part is defined of a positive real number $x$ is defined by $\{x\}:=x-\lfloor x\rfloor$.
Is it true that $$\inf_{n\in \mathbb{N}^*} \left\{\frac{3^n}{2^n} \right\} > 0 \ ?$$
If so, how could I prove it?

Not sure what a PSQ is. But here are the fist values 0.5,
0.25
0.375
0.0625
0.59375
0.390625
0.0859375
0.628906
0.443359
0.665039
0.497559
0.746338
0.619507
0.92926
0.89389
0.840836
0.261253
0.89188
0.83782
0.25673
0.885095
0.827643
0.741464
0.112196
0.168294
0.752441
0.128662
0.692992
0.039489
0.059233
0.588849
0.883274
0.824911
0.737366
0.60605
0.409075
0.613612
0.920418
0.880627
0.32094
0.48141
0.722115
0.583173
0.874759
0.312138
0.968207
0.952311
0.428466
0.1427
0.21405

I would expect this to be false - the powers of a real number mod 1 should be uniformly distributed on [0, 1] unless there's some reason to expect otherwise.  The particular case of the powers of $3/2$ has been studied.  In particular numerical evidence has been compiled in On the Uniformity of (3/2)^n Modulo 1 by P. Neeley, D. Taylor-Rodriguez, J. J. P. Veerman, T. Roth and in this blog post by John Cook.
